# ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None when specify a single host on the command line

Tags: ansible

how to set ssh or ansible_user when specify a single host on the command line?

when i specify a single host as following:

```
$ansible-playbook -i "ceph1," jdk.yml
TASK [hadoop : create hadoop group] ********************************************
task path: /playbooks/yarn/roles/hadoop/tasks/install.yml:2
<ceph1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
```

Both the ssh conneciton user and {{ansible_user}} are none, but  i have defined it in ssh/config

```
$cat jdk.yml
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
     - default.yml
  roles:
     - role: jdk

$cat role/jdk/tasks/main.yml

- name: set java home
  lineinfile: dest=/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.bashrc
              line={{ item }}
  with_items:
    - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

$cat hosts
    ceph1 ansible_user=ubuntu

$cat ~/.ssh/config
    Host ceph1
    User ubuntu
```

of course runnig the below is ok

```
$ansible-playbook  jdk.yml
```

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the -e parameter:

```
# ansible -m ping web1 -i inventory/a2  -vvv -e "ansible_user=ceph"
<a2-web1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ceph
```